# Get Critical error during Json request using Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a problem. In my company I need to try out how Angular.js works together with ASP.NET MVC. Now I want to create a simple little application. On the front page there is a view with a Kendo UI grid. Inside my `App.js` file I read data from my `Data` Controller. The Controller Action gets called but as soon as the  code is done executing I get the following error:

[image: Error Message from Visual Studio]

Here is the rest of my Code:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetEmergencyRegions([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string searchterm)
{
    var emergencyRegions = _repository.GetEmergencyRegionBySearchTerm(searchterm);
    return Json(emergencyRegions.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**App.js**

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columns: [{
        field: "Description",
        title: "Beschreibung"
    }, {
        field: "Region",
        title: "Region"
    }, {
        field: "Phone",
        title: "Telefon"
    }, {
        field: "HasPointOfSale",
        title: "PoS"
    }],
    pageable: true,
    dataSource: {
        pageSize: 5,
        transport: {
            read: function (e) {
                $http.jsonp('/Data/GetEmergencyRegions')
                  .then(function success(response) {
                      e.success(response.data);
                  }, function error(response) {
                      alert('something went wrong')
                      console.log(response);
                  })
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**View with the Grid**

```
<kendo-grid options="gridOptions">

</kendo-grid>
```

On Stackoverflow I already found something with adding `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` to the `jsonp URL` but it didn't help.

**Notice**

When I remove the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` inside my Controller, I don't get the error but then I get the `status Code 404`.

Comment: if you use jsonp you have to add that callback, is the error still the same with the callback?

Comment: @koox00 Yes same error with the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
There were several things to change:

1. Remove `DataSourceRequest` part in Controller. With this change the critical JavaScript error disapears.

   ```
   public JsonResult GetEmergencyRegions(string searchterm)
   {
       var emergencyRegions = _repository.GetEmergencyRegionBySearchTerm(searchterm);
       return Json(emergencyRegions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```
2. I now had a 404 error again in my App.js. Solution for that is changing `jsonp` to `get`.  I found this solution in the following link: [AngularJS: how to make a jsonp request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916362/angularjs-how-to-make-a-jsonp-request)

   ```
   read: function (e) {
        $http.get('/Data/GetEmergencyRegions?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .then(function success(response) {
                 e.success(response.data);
             }, function error(response) {
                 alert('something went wrong')
                 console.log(response);
        })
   }
   ```
3. Run the Solution and be Happy :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seem you redundant "," in App.js

Change

```
 columns: [{
    field: "Description",
    title: "Beschreibung",
},
```

to

```
 columns: [{
    field: "Description",
    title: "Beschreibung"
},
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Maybe help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507334/net-mvc-updated-jquery-now-getting-critical-error

Comment: Hmm my Bundle.config looks good I think no problems there but Thanks :)

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543115/get-critical-error-during-json-request-using-kendo-ui/34543445#34543445