# MVC 4 and bundles

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

On my local machine, this script tag works great.  It includes several scripts

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

all from this line in my bundles.config file.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/js/jquery.unobtrusive*",
    "~/js/jquery.validate*"));
```

And on the contact form (this is a really small site) when I click the "Submit" button, validation happens client side and doesn't submit the form unless all required fields are filled in.  I can verify that all of the scripts I need are being loaded.

When I publish the site, however, no "not found" errors happen, but it doesn't load any jquery.unobtrusive or jquery.validate scripts.  If you click on submit on the contact form, the page does a server round trip, which is not what I want.

If I manually add the scripts via a  tag and reload the page, then the validation happens client side.

I've verified the paths are the correct, and Chrome isn't reporting any missing files, etc.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you positive that you don't have JavaScript disabled for your site? In chrome you can disable JavaScript on a site basis...

Comment: Please try `~/js/jquery.unobstrusive.js` instead of `"~/js/jquery.unobstrusive*"`

Comment: @Icarus, I'm positive.

Answer (score 1):

What version of JQuery are you using?

I've had similar problem in the past using JQuery 1.9.0.

If you are in the same situation, you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402741/jquery-1-9-0-and-modernizr-cannot-be-minified-with-the-asp-net-web-optimization).

Comment: I am, and I think that is on the right track.  However, I followed those instructions to the letter, and no dice.  However, I do see that some code somewhere is pulling the 1.9.0 file from googleapis.com.  So, instead of fighting it, I'm going to just manually put in the scripts for now.  I'll come back and update this when I get more time.  Thanks for the pointer, though.