# Minification error JQuery in MVC Bundle

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, minify

After publishing my web application to azure the Jquery Script bundle contains this header:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(1447,2-3): run-time warning JS1195: Expected expression: *
(1447,31-32): run-time warning JS1004: Expected ';': c
(1448,4-13): run-time warning JS1030: Conditional compilation is turned off: @requires
 */
/*! jQuery v2.0.3 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-2.0.3.min.map
*/
```

I have this Bundle registration:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.sitespecific.js",
                    "~/Scripts/sitespecific.js",
                    "~/Scripts/autonumeric.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.coolfieldset.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/custom/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/custom/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css",
                    "~/Content/jquery.coolfieldset.css"));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402741/jquery-1-9-0-and-modernizr-cannot-be-minified-with-the-asp-net-web-optimization.

Comment: I checked the info from that link and it should have been fixed. The line //@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-2.0.3.min.map is no longer the last line and surrounded by /* */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared to be the jquery plugin jquery.coolfieldset.js. After adding a linefeed at the end and beginning of this file the minification worked